# res.redirect() not working in chrome - Found. Redirecting to

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express, redirect

Getting this weird one

[image]

this is post call in express.js which contains redirect.

```
app.post('/callback', (req, res)=> {
res.redirect('/deal')
});
```

this is my get call in express.js

```
app.get('/deal', (req, res) => {
     console.log("node.js /deal")
});
```

*Above one working fine*

**UPDATE:** 
Real trouble here.

express:

```
app.post('/callback', (req, res)=> {
    res.redirect('')
    });
```

angular2-cli:

```
path: '',
redirectTo: '/deals'
component: PublicDealsComponent
```

Why I'm saying weird is it working perfectly in Microsoft-edge but not in chrome. what would be the reason ? how to make it work in chrome?

Comment: what output are you getting on console ?

Comment: Response headers all look okay when you check in network panel?

Comment: @professionallyme86 could you have a look on update one. In this, there is no output in console(_empty_).

Comment: @CBroe  seems fine(and looks same as microsoft-edge ).
General:
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/callback
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found(yellow)
Remote Address:[::1]:3000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Yes i am able to recreate the issue at my end . It is because you are trying to redirect to and empty string.

Comment: @professionallyme86 yes I'm agreed with you but it working in Microsoft-edge which redirecting me to /deals(angular2) when empty string occurs that makes me panic.

Comment: For what are you using angular here ? Can you explain your flow ?

Comment: @professionallyme86  just imagine angular contain PublicDealComponent and auth login where user need to login to get publicDeal content, path is _/deals_  . auth will post a form to _/callback_ catching the required content in express js and redirecting to _/deals_ to retrieve the content from PublicDealComponent.

Comment: As you said express will redirect to /deals , but you are redirecting to ""

Comment: @professionallyme86 express need to redirect _/deals_ when we had _empty string_ ' '

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you cannot redirect a user to an empty `string ('')`.
If you want a redirect to your home route without a '`/`' in the end then you can actually use the `req.protocol` and `req.host` from the request. You can refer the code below:

`res.redirect(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host'));`